# Meaning of [^:]: format string in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I found this in some code and could not understand what it does:

```
scanf("%[^:]:%[^:]:%[^:\n]", a, b, c);
```

There was no mention of the `[^:]:` format string in the C documentation and I am quite confused.

Comment: How did you google? Because [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) is the first result I get when I google **scanf** and there is explanation for `[^characters]`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510715/negated-scanset-in-fscanf-and-eof

Comment: I just re-googled it and 4 other links are visited, and I skipped that one because it said C++.  Would it still apply?

Comment: and to add to @YuHao 's comment, those `symbols` are sometimes called `format specifiers`. :-)

Comment: @JavaBob - Yes it would still apply.

Comment: The only definitive C documentation out there is the text is the ISO standard. It contains what you need in the description of `fscanf` (§7.21.6.2 in the current version). If your reference material doesn't describe all conversion specifiers defned there, use a better reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important thing you should remember is, scanf() function accepts the arguments how it is specified.

For example:

scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
assuming a and b are integer.

In the command line you have to input a and then followed by space and then b.because you have given a space in-between two "%d's". if you are giving n number of spaces are other character then you have to enter in-between those character before the value gets accepted.

Hence in your case:

you enter the string not containing ":" in it.

Consider this case, if you want to  enter a string containing ":" in it.

For example:

"some:init" is the string then, in first %[^:] the string "some" is stored,then comes the ":" and then in second %[^:] it stores init. Then it wait for one more ":" and then the string not containing ":".

ultimately accepting the input in this format doesn't fetch any thing.

The only thing matters is how you print it on to the console.

Comment: "you have to input a and then followed by space and then b.because you have given a space in-between two `"%d's"` ..." is incorrect as well as the next sentence.  `' '` in `scanf()` does not perform as answered here.  `scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);` nicely accepts "1 2" as input.  `"%d"` will consume leading white space.  It does not need to be `" %d"`.  Aside from `"%["`, any white-space in a `scanf()` format acts the same: directs `scanf()` to consume 0 or more of any white-space.

Answer (score 2):

The format string %[..] is for specifying the possible characters. For example %[A-DF] is for A, B, C, D, and F. And the ^ at the beginning is for any character excluding the characters specified. Hence, the first format string is for reading characters excluding colon. And the next is colon, and so on. You may test the scanf for the following input:

```
Adam:And:Apple
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you say the next is colon, do you mean that it also reads all characters excluding colon, or do you mean something else?